# Loading UIViewController "from" Nib File

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am trying to create an `UIViewController` from a Nib file. On Google I found that I can only load an UIView from Nib.

But some suggests that I could create a Nib file (of UIView) whose File Owner is set to our `ViewController`.

That is what I did, I got no crashes, but the View is just not displayed.

EDIT: 
Tried to push the `viewcontroller` like this

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(CoolViewController(), animated: true );
```

But it still showing black screen when it is pushed

XCode 6.3 - Not using Storyboards

Comment: I'm able to load UIViewControllers from nibs.  Could you post the source code that you use to attempt the load?  I don't use storyboards either.

Comment: I have just tried to Create a UIViewControler and check the "Also Create Xib" checkbox. And push it using 
            self.navigationController!.pushViewController(CoolViewController(), animated: true );

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to allocate your `ViewController`, then initialize it by telling the iOS the name of the nib.

I see you're using Swift; I'm afraid I don't know swift, only objective-c.  But here is how it would be done in objective-c:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController [[[CoolViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"CoolDesign" bundle: nil] autorelease];
```

... where "CoolDesign" is the base name of your nib.  That is, you create CoolDesign.xib in Interface Builder, Xcode compiles the XML - text - xib into CoolDesign.nib, then you tell initWithNibName to open just @"CoolDesign".

It's not enough just to tell Interface Builder that a design document is a `UIViewController`.  While in principle the iOS could figure out what you mean, also in principle you could have multiple nibs for a single `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: This is not preferred. The nib should load without referencing the name.

Comment: @benjaminhallock you can have call method to return the nib name generally we name the xib file with same name.`NSStringFromClass([self class])`

Comment: @Max No, the nib is attached without reference.

Comment: @benjaminhallock can you show a tutorial that doesn't require referencing the name and instead use another way? I'm rather new with nibs.

Answer (score 31):

Try this, you can load a `UIViewController` with `nibName:`

**Swift**

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(CoolViewController(nibName: "CoolViewControllerNibName", bundle: nil), animated: true )
```

**Objective-C**

```
CoolViewController*coolViewCtrlObj=[[CoolViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CoolViewControllerNibName" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:coolViewCtrlObj  animated:YES];
```