# Swift - Slide Menu Transtion between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, menu, slide

I'm working for a IOS9+ project using swift ,
using the same slide menu (Which is done programmatically) to translate between view controllers as shown in the link : [Slide Menu](https://github.com/PhilippeBoisney/Swift-Slide-Menu) and it working fine

the problem is it's using storyboard ID for each view controller in the  function addChildView():

```
 func addChildView(storyBoardID: String, titleOfChildren: String, iconName: String) {

let childViewToAdd: UIViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyBoardID)
tabOfChildViewController += [childViewToAdd]
tabOfChildViewControllerName += [titleOfChildren]
tabOfChildViewControllerIconName += [iconName]

menuToReturn.append(["title":titleOfChildren, "icon":iconName])
}
```

which is called in TransitionBetweenTwoViews function :

```
func transitionBetweenTwoViews(subViewNew: UIViewController){

//Add new view
addChildViewController(subViewNew)
subViewNew.view.frame = (self.parentViewController?.view.frame)!
view.addSubview(subViewNew.view)
subViewNew.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

 //Remove old view
 if self.childViewControllers.count > 1 {

 //Remove old view
 let oldViewController: UIViewController = self.childViewControllers.first!
 oldViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
 oldViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
 oldViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
 }

 print("After Remove: \(self.childViewControllers.description)")
 }
```

that is called in the delegate of the BaseViewController Class

My problem is that I'm not using storyboard instead a nib file for each view controller , how could i do it without storyboard I have been searching for days to find solution but nothing work
Also the tableView of the menu is a table with sections

Please if you have any solution that could help it will be appreciated 
or any other slide menu that work with nib files

**Edit :**
Slide Menu table View :
[screen shot of slide menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqsyB.png) with section so if i choose Flight Availability or Ticket Balance it will be like i choose home with index 0 how could i solve that ?

Comment: Use the `MyViewController(nibName:)` initialiser - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316257/loading-uiviewcontroller-from-nib-file

Comment: how could it define the selected nib view controller ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you want a `MyChildVC1` you say `let childViewToAdd = MyChildVC1(nibName:"mychildVC")` - substituting class names and nib names as appropriate

Comment: Thanks a lot it work fine but i still have problem with selection